# Child frame opens a popup. How do I check if that popup is opened from the parent?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page contains a frame. From within this frame I can open up a popup. How can I tell if this popup is opened from the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.opener && 
    window.opener.top === window.opener) {
    // this window was opened from a window that is it's own top (not an IFrame)
}
```